# How can I find the change in runtime per unit change in the size of input with an O(n log n) time complexity?

Tags: c, algorithm, time-complexity, runtime, big-o

If the runtime of a program is 4.956 seconds with an input size of 10,000,000, what would the runtime be if I increased the size of the input to 20,000,000 with an O(n log n) time complexity (approximate runtime)?

Comment: The complexity can be hiding a 4.5 seconds constant warmup time and still be O(n log n). So strictly speaking this has no good answer. But the only thing you can do with the information you have is substitute n1 & n2 into the formula and use the ratio. Are you asking how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming negligible startup time, the ratio should be approximately

*(2n.log(2n))/(n.log(n))*

which simplifies to

*(2.(log(n) + log(2)))/log(n)*

*2.(1 + log(2)/log(n))*

So from 10 to 20 million, the ratio is just above 2 at approximately 2.086, giving an approximate run time of **10.34s**.

Yet be aware that other factors besides the algorithm time complexity may affect the run time significantly, such as CPU cache sizes and memory overcommitment, so the observed timings for large sample sizes may not follow the expected curve.

Comment: @teapot418: thank you for double checking, mental calculation bug :)